# Establecer prioridad en una aplicacion en c#

Tags: c#

Hola estaba intentando bajar la prioridad de mi aplicación para de esa manera limitar el consumo de recursos pero de momento no sé muy bien si bajando la prioridad podría evitarlo. Como no me funciono pensé en ponerlo como un thread un hilo y de esa manera limitar la ejecución del mismo o bajarle la prioridad, pero no estoy muy seguro si sea la manra indicada. Lo que quiero es que mi aplicación este limitada en el consumo de cpu, recursos etc..

Mi pregunta si mi aplicación consume mucho se puede limitar el consumo de recursos o de cpu para limitarla o alguna manera de evitarlo?

Comment: A parte de la respuesta de @ErlantzCalvo, yo te diría que si tu aplicación consume demasiados recursos,es probable que necesites analizar porque es esto, y si debes rediseñarla para que no sea asi...

Comment: esque puede que no formulase bien me pregunta tambien me refería al tema de doble nucleo un solo nucleo cuando tu le das a setafinnity en taskmgr te permite elegir si la aplicacion arranca en doble nucle o un solo nucleo esto no se podría indicar en c#??

Comment: Para usar mas de un nucleo, debes hacer uso de la [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd537609(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Si le pongo System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr) 1; mi aplicación correria en un solo núcleo?

Comment: Ese método no es aplicable a una aplicación winforms, es del XNA studio que ademas no se si es obsoleto

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta a *si mi aplicación consume mucho se puede limitar el consumo de recursos o de cpu para limitarla o alguna manera de evitarlo?* es **No**. De esa tarea se encarga el sistema operativo. Como bien dices, la mejor manera de tratar con el consumo de CPU es cambiar la prioridad de la aplicación de la siguiente manera:

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;`

Comment: te indico lo k cite a pikoh  me refería al tema de doble nucleo un solo nucleo cuando tu le das a setafinnity en taskmgr te permite elegir si la aplicacion arranca en doble nucle o un solo nucleo esto no se podría indicar en c#??